# preg_replace_callback (regex) if string doesn't contain character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm attempting to make the preg_replace_callback return a match only if it doesn't contain a certain character.

So if the string contains:

```
{xxxx}
```

return a match.
If it contains:

```
{xxxx|xxxx}
```

Don't return a match.

Here's my attempt:

```
\{(.*?!\|.*)}
```

Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your full pattern will be this:

```
/{([^|]*)}/
```

Match any character that's not a pipe, wrapped around curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). Here's "any character *except* `|`":

```
[^|]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `/{([^|])*}/`. It will match any string without `|` character, and even empty string.

This is more of a "blacklisting" approach. If you have an idea of what the valid characters are, you should use the "whitelist" approach (listing of characters allowed in the character class `[]`), since the current approach will also allow characters such as `#$!@~<?>":'{}[]` in the string.

Comment: Why is it when I apply this change it crashes my localhost apache server?